# Entity Framework enum property is ignored by code first

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5, code-first

Okay, the problem is this. I have multiple models that make use of enum properties, in all but one of them I've had no problem with this. In this model however code first does not recognise this property and will not create a column in the respective table. What's bizarre is that I have a very similar model to the non-functioning one that works fine, the only difference being that it's in a different namespace.

I'll add that:

- My project is targeting .NET 4.5 (and indeed the functioning and non-functioning models are within the same project).
- I'm using Entity Framework 5
- My enums are defined publicly in the namespace, **not** nested within a class.

This eliminates the most common causes of problems when trying to use enums in EF.

Here are the code snippets, first the non-working one:

```
public enum Commodities
{
    Test1,
    Test2,
    Test3
}

[Table("Suppliers")]
public class Suppliers
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(7)]
    [Display(Name = "Vendor ID")]
    public string VendorID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Supplier Name")]
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public Commodities Commodity { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}
```

Now here is one that works fine, only difference being that it's in a different namespace and class file (both sit in the same project and have identical using declarations):

```
public enum Commodities
{
    Test4,
    Test5,
    Test6
}

[Table("Buyers")]
public class Buyer
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Display(Name = "Buyer ID")]
    [Required]
    public string BuyerID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Buyer Name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Windows Logon ID")]
    public string WinUserID { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail adress")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Commodities Commodity { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Active?")]
    public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

In the "Buyer" table code first correctly initialising the Commodity column and maps it to the enum in the model. In the "Suppliers" table however it's only initialised with the columns: VendorID, VendorName, and Visible with Commodity no where to be found. My question is why is this happening and what can I do to fix it? I'm at my wits end with this.

EDIT: Seems the issue might have to do with using two enums with the same name. Although the compiler has no complaints about ambiguity (and it shouldn't as they exist in different namespaces) it seems EF doesn't like it. Changing the name of one of the enums causes CF to recognise the property.